# Running Pycharm as root from launcher

Tags: linux, ubuntu, pycharm, root, sudo

How is it possible to run Pycharm from the launcher with root privileges?

I can do that from the terminal window, with `sudo ./pycharm.sh`, but I'd like to do the same directly from the launcher.

Comment: I'm not familiar with pycharm but this article may be what you're looking for: http://esmithy.net/2015/05/05/rundebug-as-root-in-pycharm/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have encountered another way to solve this issue so I thought to share it (this answer is more like an alternative for the other answers).

It is worth to mention that this solution "attacks" the problem by running only a certain Python script (within the PyCharm IDE) in root mode , and not the entire PyCharm application.

**1) Disable** requiring password for running Python:

Recommend using the visudo program to edit the file to ensure syntax is correct. Otherwise you may be locked out of using sudo.

`visudo /etc/sudoers.d/python`

What we need to do is add an entry in that file as follows:

`user host = (root) NOPASSWD: full_path_to_python` , for example:

`guya ubuntu = (root) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/python`

NOTES:

`user` can be detected by the command: `whoami`

`host` can be detected by the command: `hostname`

**2) Create** a "sudo script": The purpose of this script is to give python privilege to run as root user.

Create a script called `python-sudo.sh` , and add the following into it:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo /usr/bin/python "$@"
```

Note, again, that the path is the path to your Python as the previous phase.

Don't forget to give execution permissions to this script using the command: `chmod`, i.e.-

`chmod +x python-sudo.sh`

**3) Use** the `python-sudo.sh` script as your PyCharm interpreter:

Within PyCharm go to: `File --> Settings --> Project interpreter`

At the right top hand side click the "setting" icon, and click "Add local".

In the browser option choose the `python-sudo.sh` script we have created previously. This will give PyCharm the privilege to run a python script as root.

**4) Debug** the test: All there is left to do is actually debug the specific Python script in the PyCharm IDE. This can be done easily via Right-click on the script to debug --> hit "Debug sample_script_to_debug.py"

Comment: This did not work for me, it corrupted my sudoers file, and that was a whole adventure... Along with PyCharm (and IntelliJ) spitting out `invalid interpreter` & so I tried it anyway, just doesn't work. -1 from me (this is on ubuntu btw)

Comment: This work for me,
in the project folder: 
sudo chmod -R 777 ./

Answer (score 10):

Try: `gksudo ./path/to/pycharm/executable`

More about [`gksudo`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gksudo)

If you're on ubuntu and don't have `gksudo` install it using:

```
apt-get install gksu
```

Here is an example launcher configuration (under: `~/.local/share/applications/jetbrains-pycharm-ce.desktop`):

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=PyCharm Community Edition
Icon=/home/YOUR_USER/pycharm/bin/pycharm.png
Exec=gksudo -k -u root "/home/YOUR_USER/pycharm/bin/pycharm.sh" %f
Comment=Develop with pleasure!
Categories=Development;IDE;
Terminal=false
StartupWMClass=jetbrains-pycharm-ce
```

- `ce` indicates community edition, yours may differ.

Comment: Thanks, but i'd like to avoid going into the terminal window, and run as root directly from the launcher's icon if possible.

Comment: yes, it launches the app as my current user, which is not root.

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly I was looking for!

Comment: How about for a flatpak Pycharm install?

Answer (score 2):

As of this post (June 28 2018) I am running Pycharm-2018.1.4 on Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver. The solution that worked for me was to simply edit the `sudoers.d` file and add the following to the last line:

`user host = (root) NOPASSWD: full_path_to_python`

for example:

`guya surface-pro = (root) NOPASSWD /usr/bin/python3.6`

Comment: this means that every python script will have root permissions. While it is a correct answer to the question I wouldn't implement this solution because it is really dangerous.

Answer (score 2):

I had the need to run a script from PyCharm as root like the OP, but the accepted answer didn't work for me because 1.) I had installed PyCharm via flatpak and 2.) The `gksu` command isn't available on newer versions of Ubuntu and Mint.

I couldn't find a way to make things work consistently with the flatpak install so I uninstalled the PyCharm flatpak and then reinstalled PyCharm the "normal" way.  The accepted answer relies on the `gksu` command which is not available on my OS (Mint 19.2).  Thankfully `pkexec` is a suitable alternative and was already available on my system.  I then updated my launcher file (~/.local/share/applications/PyCharm.desktop) as follows.  The important bit is the `Exec` line:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=PyCharm
Exec=pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY /opt/pycharm-community-2019.2.2/bin/pycharm.sh
Comment=PyCharm
Terminal=false
Icon=/opt/pycharm-community-2019.2.2/bin/pycharm.png
Type=Application
```

The `pkexec` command will cause a popup to appear prompting you for your password each time you launch PyCharm via the `.desktop` file.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sample git repo that is a proof-of-concept for how to do this. Should be as simple as following the instructions in the `README.md`. My team needed to do this for one of our products and we used that as the workflow.

Hope this helps! https://github.com/samayer12/sudome

This answer builds upon the description [here](http://esmithy.net/2015/05/05/rundebug-as-root-in-pycharm/) that was first pointed out by Ed Jones.

Answer (score 0):

I have Pycharm-community 2020.
I edited the

```
/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/pycharm-community_pycharm-community.desktop
```

file with nano
just modified the Desktop Entry as follow:

```
[Desktop Entry]
X-SnapInstanceName=pycharm-community
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=root PyCharm Community Edition
Icon=/snap/pycharm-community/222/bin/pycharm.png
Exec=sudo env BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT=/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/pycharm-community_pycharm-community.desktop /snap/bin/pycharm-community %f
Comment=root Python IDE for Professional Developers
Categories=Development;IDE;
Terminal=false
StartupWMClass=jetbrains-pycharm-ce
StartupNotify=true
```

that is: added the `sudo` command in front of the EXEC item, put "root" in front of couple of fields (see above) and saved with a different name:

```
/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/root_pycharm-community_pycharm-community.desktop
```

now I have two icons in the launcher, one that is the standard and the other one with "root" as leading word in the description and runs as root.

**Note:**
the original desktop launcher (which is still there):

```
[Desktop Entry]
X-SnapInstanceName=pycharm-community
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=PyCharm Community Edition
Icon=/snap/pycharm-community/222/bin/pycharm.png
Exec=env BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT=/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/pycharm-community_pycharm-community.desktop /snap/bin/pycharm-community %f
Comment=Python IDE for Professional Developers
Categories=Development;IDE;
Terminal=false
StartupWMClass=jetbrains-pycharm-ce
StartupNotify=true
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution:
In the project folder:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 ./
```

This just give write permission.