# install quandl in pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, quandl

I am trying to install quandl in PyCharm. I am trying to do this by going into project interpreter clicking the "+" button and then selecting Quandl. I am getting the following error.

OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/raysabbineni/Library/Python/2.7'

I have installed pandas and sklearn in the above way so I'm  not sure what the error with quandl is.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with the specific package you are installing. You need to install with root rights or use virtual environments (which don't require root rights & are a better solution anyhow)

Comment: can you give me more information on installing a package with root rights in pycharm

Comment: without rights: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14179941/how-to-install-python-packages-without-root-privileges

Comment: What OS is this? Mac or Linux?

Comment: Running pycharm as root https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36530082/running-pycharm-as-root-from-launcher

Answer (score 2):

```
import quandl
```

Within Python 3 or Pycharm you can not uppercase "Q" in quandl. same case like import tkinter, not Tkinter as before

Comment: Those minimum character limits are there to force you to be descriptive and explain. Don't fill it up with garbage.

Answer (score 1):

try with sudo pip install (your package) on the terminal
sudo pip install quandl
Or
Sudo easy_install quandl

Comment: I am able to install it on terminal using sudo pip install quandl --user python. However, I am not able to access it in pycharm. My understanding was that I need to install it using pycharm to import quandl in pycharm

Comment: In this case check where you install it like with which version of python. There is a chance that you install it with python 2.7 while you are using python 3 like interpreter on pycharm.

Comment: I have python 2.7 installed and am using python 2.7 in the interpreter on pycharm

Comment: Try refreshing pycharm

Comment: Go on the menu of pycharm view->terminal and then try to command pip install quandl in the terminal of pycharm. There is no way that it will not work

Comment: so the terminal local to my pycharm does not work. I get an error that says Can't open local terminal java.io.exception